# How can I run a celery periodic task from the shell manually?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I'm using celery and django-celery. I have defined a periodic task that I'd like to test. Is it possible to run the periodic task from the shell manually so that I view the console output?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Have you tried just running the task from the Django shell? You can use the `.apply` method of a task to ensure that it is run eagerly and locally.

Assuming the task is called `my_task` in Django app `myapp` in a `tasks` submodule:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from myapp.tasks import my_task
>>> eager_result = my_task.apply()
```

The result instance has the same API as the usual `AsyncResult` type, except that the result is always evaluated eagerly and locally and the `.apply()` method will block until the task is run to completion.

Comment: How can I do the same for pyramid project? The directory structure will be like:
/myproject=>
    celeryconfig.py,
    setup.py,
    development.py,
    /views/celerytasks=>
        mycelerytask.py

.Now here I want to run 'mycelerytask.py'(which is periodic task) manually from command line. Can you help?

Comment: @Workonphp I'm not familiar with Pyramid, unfortunately, so I don't know how Celery integrates with Pyramid at all. (Note that my solution above is Django-specific, requiring the `manage.py` script Django generates in all Django project directories.) Sorry.

Answer (score 43):

If you means just trigger a task when the condition is not satisfied, for example, the periodic time not meet. You can do it in two steps.

**1.Get your task id.**

You can do it by typing.

```
celery inspect registered
```

You will see something like `app.tasks.update_something`. 
If nothing, it is probably that `celery` was not started. Just run it.

**2.Run the task with `celery call`**

```
celery call app.tasks.update_something
```

For more details, just type

```
celery --help
celery inspect --help
celery call --help
```

Comment: it also supports args and kwargs 
$ celery -A yourapp call app.tasks.update_something --kwargs='{"key": value,...}

Comment: This is very helpful, but missing a parenthesis at the end. Corrected: `celery -A yourapp call app.tasks.update_something --kwargs='{"key": value,...}'`

Comment: Although `inspect` is great, unfortunately it is only available for "RabbitMQ (AMQP) and Redis transports." (not others like `filesystem` for instance)

Comment: In order for `celery call` command to work with the Redis backend, the Celery result backend needs to be configured correctly as well. It should be set to a URL rather than simply to "redis". Source: https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1278#issuecomment-738006032

Comment: Running `celery call <task>` this way yields me this: `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

Answer (score 11):

I think you'll need to open two shells: one for executing tasks from the Python/Django shell, and one for running `celery worker` (`python manage.py celery worker`). And as the previous answer said, you can run tasks using `apply()` or `apply_async()`

I've edited the answer so you're not using a deprecated command.

Comment: manage.py celeryd is deprecated now:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23921568/1459594