# How to process unfinished tasks in django celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am working on a project in which zip/gzip files are uploaded by the user and then unzipped and processed using Celery. The website is based on Django. 
Now the problem that I am facing is that there are few files that have been uploaded when Celery was not running. Is there anyway that I can re-run celery for such unprocessed files? If so, then how?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the celery automatically starts task that's initiated when the celery was not running. Run `./manage.py celeryd -lDEBUG`, and see in the terminal.

Comment: umm, it has outputted a lot of lines. What can I actually do with that?

Comment: It runs the celery in the debug mode. You should see something like `Task Accepted` which means your task has begun.

Comment: actually, RabbitMQ is used on production server. and I think the service was not activated when some files were uploaded. Now the problem is that although the related data for the files( like filename , file types etc) is posted in the database, but the files were not unzipped and processed. Can you suggest me a workaround for this?

Comment: Hm in that case, you have to start those tasks manually from `Django shell`. You need to track down the ID of the task and run it manually. These two links will help you: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900023/how-can-i-run-a-celery-periodic-task-from-the-shell-manually

Comment: Thats really cool Thanks a lot. But how can I find out that which task was failed and which was not? and how do I get the id of that task?

Answer (score 0):

You have to track down those tasks manually and start them from `Django shell`. There are lots of tables that celery creates to keep track of those tasks. It's been a while that I haven't used celery but still my guess would be:

```
djcelery_crontabschedule

djcelery_taskstate
```

There might be something about this on celery documentation too: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.3/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html

You can also ask your query on celery mailing list.