# Failure to start celeryd - Error : conflicting option string(s): --no-color

Tags: django, celery

I'm using django v1.7.0b4 and celery v3.1.1. Followed steps according to the [django installation guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). But I'm stuck with the below error.

```
$ ./manage.py celeryd --help
Starting server in DEVELOPMENT Mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 427, in     execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django_celery-3.1.10-py2.7.egg/djcelery/management/base.py", line 77, in run_from_argv
return super(CeleryCommand, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 284, in run_from_argv
parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 265, in create_parser
option_list=self.option_list)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1214, in __init__
add_help=add_help_option)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1256, in _populate_option_list
self.add_options(option_list)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1039, in add_options
self.add_option(option)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1020, in add_option
self._check_conflict(option)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 995, in _check_conflict
option)
optparse.OptionConflictError: option -C/--no-color: conflicting option string(s): --no-color
```

Is any one else facing the same issue ?

Edited :

Working good in django v1.6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `./manage.py celery worker` instead of `./manage.py celeryd`

Looks like there is an bug when you use:

```
django==1.7b4
celery==3.1.11
django-celery==3.1.10
```

Few tips which will help you avoid this issues:

- When you are starting playing with a project stay away from beta releases, use stable release.
- Don't use deprecated methods: `./manage.py celeryd` is old deprecated alias for `./manage celery worker`

Comment: Yes, I should not have meddled with the beta release. "celery worker" was also crashing so I went with "celeryd" with a change in file "celery/bin/base.py". Things are working fine with django v1.6.5 now. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget if you are using celerycam → "celery events  -c djcelery.snapshot.Camera"

Answer (score 1):

The incompatibility in django-celery was fixed two months ago: https://github.com/celery/django-celery/pull/320. If you are using virtualenv, then you could monkey-patch like this:

```
sed "s/\(= \['--app', '--loader', '--config'\)\]/\1, '--no-color']/"  -i \
    "$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/djcelery/management/base.py"
```

Tested with Celery 3.1.13 and django-celery 3.1.10.