# talk to celery inside docker

Tags: docker, celery

I'm running celery-worker and celery-beat inside docker.

When I do `celery logs -f celery-worker` I can see the celery is up and running

Now I want to send some tasks (for test purposes) to the worker..

There seems to be two ways to do that ([How can I run a celery periodic task from the shell manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900023/how-can-i-run-a-celery-periodic-task-from-the-shell-manually))
using `django shell` and using `celery` command itself
I don't have manage.py in the docker, so I'm using the `celery` command

However, all celery commands including `celery inspect registered` hangs and gives me nothing.

How can I send tasks to celery running inside docker?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it hangs because you cannot connect to the broker.

You need the `CELERY_BROKER_URL` environment variable to be set to the correct url before running `celery` commands.

If you are using docker compose you should have a broker service more or less similar to this:

```
  broker:
    container_name: broker
    image: redis:6.0
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/redis_data:/data
```

Basically we can connect to our broker from our host machine using localhost:6379 .

Therefore in the terminal you can set the following env var

```
$ export CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379/0
```

and celery commands should return a result now.